# How can I make the display consistent for column header in FullCalendar v5 for a particular view?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When I resize my window in TimeGridWeek view, the `weekday` text i.e Mon, Wed, etc moves to the next line for some of the days and stays in the same line as date for some of the days. How can I standardise the column headers in such a manner where if one of the weekdays shifts down to the next line, all other weekdays in other columns shift down too. Attaching the screenshot of the problem for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Not reproducible using the default settings - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWpogMK . I'd guess either your CSS theme or some other setting is interfering. We don't have any relevant code so we can't be more specific.

Comment: Unless you're just viewing it on a very small screen perhaps?